# Admin Panel & Home Pages Not loading properly

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

After successful installation of Magento 2.3.3.

The admin panel showing a blank screen or not loading properly.

The default theme is not loaded on the homepage.

There are errors on console also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Change the local.xml.sample to local.xml which is in pub/error  so you can know what is error in admin panel?

Comment: @Enigmativity There are a lot of questions like this one on this platform.

Comment: @Jinesh I appreciate your suggestion but I provided the solution in the answer section. I was searching for this issue for a long time but I couldn't find any, so I posted this here. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @SevenHell - Yes, that's right, but that doesn't make it right. All of them are off-topic too.

Comment: @Enigmativity As a less experienced developer, I can say that most people will search for this problem on this platform firstly. So I think you should reconsider your decision. I will respect every decision of yours.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install composer in your machine.

Link: https://getcomposer.org/

> Composer is necessary for PHP in Magento. It is a dependency manager for PHP.

For the blank screen of the admin panel :

Go to your project folder and then to below file -

```html
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:140
```

And replace

```html
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

with

```html
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
   return true;
}
```

For not loading properly and missing default theme:

Go to your project folder and then to below file -

```html
/var/cache -> *DELETE ALL*

/var/page_cache -> *DELETE ALL*

/var/session > *DELETE ALL*

/pub/static -> DELETE ALL ***EXCEPT .HTACCESS***
```

Now run below commands -

(Run the server before running the commands otherwise it will show an error.)

```html
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

*// If you are using Mac or Linux*

```html
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/
```